CO2 emissions for a satellite
How much CO2 emissions would producing an LEO satellite (e.g. Starlink satellite) release? I imagine there are various factors that go into this (aluminum body, electronics, battery, solar cells, etc.), so how could one go about calculating this?

Most likely it's nearly all launch emissions, but calculating launch emissions is hard since rocket fuel is only part of those emissions. The rocket programs are so darned expensive they can afford to emit a lot of CO2.
Satellites are entirely different from all other users of solar cells.
Terrestrial solar cells are almost always based on crystalline silicon. They are single-junction cells.
However, in space application, multi-junction cells are preferred, but it could be the case that for low Earth orbit, launch costs aren't so big that multi-junction cells are essential. They have multiple layers built typically on top of a gallium arsenide substrate. The intention is that the first layer captures high-energy lights, letting intermediate-energy light through. The second layer captures intermediate-energy light, letting low-energy light through. The bottommost layer captures low-energy light. The multi-junction cells are extremely expensive, so expensive their usage in terrestrial applications isn't cost-effective. But in space applications, where launching a kilogram of mass into orbit costs so much, it makes sense to create that kilogram of solar cells into a very efficient, very expensive device.
On the sister site, https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49615/rocket-fuel-cost-to-launch-1-kg-to-orbit says that 1 kg of satellite costs 14 kg LOX and 7 kg RP-1 if we target the low Earth orbit.
RP-1 is very similar to kerosene. Kerosene has 10-16 carbon atoms, let's use 13 as the midpoint. So there are 28 hydrogen atoms. 7 kg of that has 13*12.01/(28*1.008+13*12.01) * 7 kg = 5.93 kg of carbon, so it creates (2*16+12.01)/12.01 * 5.93 kg = 21.73 kg or about 22 kg of carbon dioxide.
This is for an ideal rocket. For a real rocket, Falcon 9, 123.5 tonnes of RP-1 is needed for 16 tonnes of payload, or 7.72 kg of RP-1. That would translate to about 28 kg of carbon dioxide.
So the fuel emissions alone are 28 kg of CO2 / kg of payload.
However, Falcon 9 cost per launch is 70 million USD and cost to build it is 16 million USD, whereas propellant is only 0.2 million USD. It is not fully reusable. So we can assume the CO2 footprint of the rocket can be much larger than the CO2 footprint of the fuel. Unfortunately, information on this is very hard to find. The second stage (not reusable) weighs 3900 kg empty. It's made of aluminum-lithium skin. World average emissions for aluminum are 16 kg / kg, so that's 62400 kg of CO2 alone for aluminum, or about 4 kg / kg of payload.
So it's at least 32 kg of CO2 / kg of payload for the materials alone, but likely much higher than that, since manufacturing the rocket's reusable and non-reusable parts has a CO2 cost, and also the reusable first stage may not be infinitely reusable and may require replacement of some component parts even though the first stage itself is considered reusable.
Aluminum body would be 16 kg / kg, world average CO2 emissions. Much less than launching it into orbit.
Single-junction cells have 1.8 kg / watt emissions from manufacturing, but in space applications, multi-junction cells (more expensive, more emissions) may be preferable.
The Aalto-1 satellite has 30 watts of panels, or 57 kg of emissions from panels alone. It weighs 4 kg so 128 kg of launch emissions. If it's made of aluminum and has 4 kg aluminum, the aluminum emissions are 64 kg emissions.
It's hard to find information on how big batteries Aalto-1 has, but its average power use is 4.8 watts so we can assume maybe 100 watt-hours? That would weigh maybe 600 grams, perfectly possible for the small satellite. According to https://climate.mit.edu/ask-mit/how-much-co2-emitted-manufacturing-batteries Tesla Model 3 has 80 kWh pack and 2400 - 16000 kg range of emissions, so for the small Aalto-1, emissions would be 3-20 kg for the battery.
So, here's a summary:

4 kg satellite
57 kg solar panels (if single-junction silicon)
64 kg for materials in the satellite (assuming its entire weight is aluminum)
3-20 kg for battery
at least 128 kg of launch emissions (potentially far more than that, though)

So it's at least 250 kg of total emissions for a 4 kg small satellite, but potentially multiple times that, since the Falcon 9 program is so expensive they can afford to emit a lot of carbon dioxide in the program.
As for Starlink, a single satellite weighs 260 kilograms so scaling linearly from Aalto-1 by weight, it's over 16000 kg of emissions for a single satellite. Potentially far more, since the Falcon 9 launch costs are so expensive they can afford to emit a lot of CO2.
